# wix 3.6 Burn feature tree to select MSI to install

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6, burn

I need to install multiple MSIs from a single unified UI. 
I also need a 'feature' tree to let the user select which product(s) to install.

Having looked at similar questions, it seems Burn is the way to go.

Looking at [this](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-create-a-feature-tree-with-burn-td7579948.html), it seems I must write a custom BA and implement my own feature tree.
Is this correct?

It seems I'll end-up with a custom UI that won't look like the standard UI for MSIs. This seems a pity when IMHO one the great thing about MSIs is that they always present the same UI to users and have been doing so for years.

If that's the way to go, is there a simple example to get started?

Does wix3.6 really not natively support feature tree? ...seems like a pretty basic and useful feature to have IMHO ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature tree is a custom control on MSI and not available for general use. A standard tree control could be used but no one has added that feature to wixstdba. Of course, you could add the feature (start discussion on wix-devs@lists.sourceforge.net) or implement your own BA. The wixstdba code is in src\ext\BalExtension\wixstdba or for managed example there is src\Setup\WixBA. Both are reasonable places to start.